# Why are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ open subsets of the discrete metric space $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ open subsets of the discrete metric space $\{0,1\}$.

Let $S$ be a metric space. Then a subset $A \subseteq S$ is considered open if $\forall x \in A, \exists r>0$ such that $B_S(x,r)  \subseteq A$.

However, $\{0\}$ is a singleton. How do we define an open ball in $\{0\}$?

Then we would need to show that this open ball lies entirely in $\{0\}$.

I have a little trouble grasping this idea. Please tell me how this becomes possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In your space, what is the ball of radius 1/2 around 0?

Comment: You should remind yourself of the definition of $B_S(x,r)$; the crucial thing to remember (which can be intuitively confusing) is that if $S=\{0,1\}$, then $B_S(x,r)$ contains far fewer points than $B_{\mathbb{R}}(x,r)$! Balls in $S$ don't look like open balls as you would usually imagine them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a discrete metric space is defined by the metric
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq y \\ 0 & x = y \end{cases}
$$
and so in particular, in the case of $S = \{0, 1\}$, we have that $d(0, 1) = 1$. Now, a(n open) ball of radius $r$ is given by
$$
B_r(x) = \{y \in X \mid d(x,y) < r\}
$$
and in a metric space, these are our basic open sets. So what is $B_{1/2}(0)$?

Comment: It contains only the point $\{0\}$ . Am i correct?

Comment: Exactly. Since $B_r(x)$ is open for all $x, r$, it then follows that $\{0\}$ is also open.

Comment: The def'n of a discrete space X is that every subset of X is open. Any discrete space is metrizable with the metric in the A by Simon Rose.